# How do you drop trinkets?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Rebirth added the ability to drop trinkets and pills. It [used to be](http://bindingofisaac.com/post/91805830134/trinkets-and-worms-and-maps-oh-my) that you could hold the Map button for a while but that doesn't work. How does it work?

Comment: [OH GOD GET THAT SNAKE OFF ME ALREADY](http://i.imgur.com/mcTSreT.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is configured to the left <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, so just hold that button from 3 to 5 seconds. Use the right trigger (<kbd>RT</kbd>) if you are using an Xbox controller to play.

Comment: In an XBox 360 controller, use the right trigger (RT)

Comment: "A bit" is about 3-5 seconds. (Just tapping the button does a different thing...)

Comment: is that specifically `shift + l` ?, I ask because neither `l` or `L` seem to work, or they take longer than the reset timeout does.

Comment: @ThorSummoner By "L control" Charlie meant the left Control (Ctrl) key.

Answer (score 4):

For Ps4 you have to hold R2. Hope this helps

Comment: Cool. I'm playing on PS4.